Any function in Sobolev $H^{s}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ space is continuous and bounded if $s>n/2$
I'm studying this book M.E. Taylor, and M.E. Taylor, Partial Differential Equations. 1: Basic Theory, Corr. 2. print (Springer, New York Heidelberg, 1997), more specifically,
the proposition 1.3.
Proposition 1.3. If $s>n/2$ then each $u\in H^{s}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is bounded and continuous.
Proof. By the Fourier inversion formula, it suffices to prove that $\widehat{u}(\xi)$ belongs to $L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Indeed, using Cauchy's inequality, we get
$\int |\widehat{u}(\xi)|\,d\xi\leq \left(\int |\widehat{u}(\xi)|(1+|\xi|^2)^{s}\right)^{1/2}\left(\int \frac{1}{(1+|\xi|^2)^{s}}\,d\xi\right)^{1/2}$
since the last integral on the right is finite precisely for s>n/2, this completes the proof.
Question 1. Why is sufficent prove that $\widehat{u}(\xi)$ belongs to $L^1(\mathbb{R}^n$?

Hint: The Fourier transform of an $L^1$ function is continuous and bounded, and a Fourier inverse transform is nothing more than the Fourier transform of a related function.

$u=F^{-1}{v}$ with $v=\widehat{u}$ and $F^{-1}{v}\in L^1$ implies that $F^{-1}(v)$ is bounded and continuous?
